# get the sum of the json value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have json value and I found the matching of specific column geo and salessale.Along with that I want to receive the  sum of pipelinevalue .I want to finc the sum of pipeline value for 'Proposal Submitted' and 'close won' as tryFind.count .Now I got the value o

```js
const data ={
   "pipeline":{
      "data":[
         {
            "UserName":"Jaison Clinton",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"Proposal Submitted",
            "PipelineValue":"3,54,000"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Jaison Clinton",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"Proposal Submitted",
            "PipelineValue":"3,49,000"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Kaviarasan Selvaraj",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"Proposal Submitted",
            "PipelineValue":"70,000"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Vivek Sharma",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"close won",
            "PipelineValue":"13,45,000"
            
         }
      ]
   }
};
const result = data.pipeline.data.reduce((acc, lead) => {
    const tryFind = acc.find(l => l.Geo === lead.Geo && l.SalesStage === lead.SalesStage);
var PipelineValue=0;
    if (tryFind) {
        tryFind.count++;
        PipelineValue=PipelineValue+lead.PipelineValue;
    } else {
        acc.push({ Geo: lead.Geo, SalesStage: lead.SalesStage, count: 1 ,PipelineValue:PipelineValue});
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

want popeline value as 773,000 (sum of nsu geo 'proposal submitted')and 13,45,000(sum of nsu geo close won)

Comment: `3,54,000` isn't a valid format for a number in javascript

Comment: Also, you keep reinitializing PipelineValue to 0, so the `else` block will always push `0`, it couldn't push anything else.

Comment: Please confirm - is `3,54,000` meant to be `354000` or is it 3 separate numbers?

Comment: Can explain what locale your using?  `13,45,000` isn't a valid number in javascript - I can't see why one isn't `7,73,000` or the other `1,345,000`

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what locale are numbers formatted this way?  To my U.S. eyes, `70,000` looks normal, but the others all look strange.  Here they would be written as `354,000`, `349,000`, and `1,345,000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing in two lines:

```
const result = data.pipeline.data.reduce((acc,lead)=> 
               (acc+=+lead.PipelineValue.replace(/,/g,''),acc), 0);
```

OK, **edited**, now this is the summation for the different `Geo`s and `SalesStage`s:

```js
const data ={
   "pipeline":{
      "data":[
         {
            "UserName":"Jaison Clinton",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"Proposal Submitted",
            "PipelineValue":"3,54,000"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Jaison Clinton",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"Proposal Submitted",
            "PipelineValue":"3,49,000"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Kaviarasan Selvaraj",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"Proposal Submitted",
            "PipelineValue":"70,000"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Vivek Sharma",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "SalesStage":"close won",
            "PipelineValue":"13,45,000"
            
         }
      ]
   }
};
const result = Object.entries(data.pipeline.data.reduce((acc,cur) => { 
      let k=cur.Geo+'|'+cur.SalesStage;
      (acc[k]=acc[k] || []).push(+cur.PipelineValue.replace(/,/g,''))
      return acc}, {}))
    .map(e=>{
      let k=e[0].split('|'); 
      return {Geo:k[0],SalesStage:k[1],count:e[1].length,PipelineValue:e[1].reduce((a,c)=>a+c)} 
     });
console.log(result);
```

I first collect individual arrays with PipelineValues and in the last `.reduce()` part I get their length and sum them up.

Comment: Might want to read the question again - it's not the total sum, it's the sum by Geo &  SalesStage

Comment: Done. please check again.

Comment: can you please help me to the username name constraints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63051275/group-the-json-based-on-specific-field

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the commas in your PipelineValue values, you'll be able to cast those strings to numbers. If you can't change the format in the source, you can do it easily in your script:

```js
// Original line
PipelineValue=PipelineValue+lead.PipelineValue;

// Replace commas with nothing, then cast as number (using unary +)
PipelineValue=PipelineValue+(+lead.PipelineValue.replace(/,/g,''));
```

Comment: This fix alone isn't enough, see my comment above.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the question states to find the sum of PipelineValue, not to convert it to a number

Comment: It also won't fix it because PipelineValue isn't being used...

Comment: Are you sure `3,54,000` should be `354,000`?  or should it be `57`?

Comment: My bad, I just focused on the fact of it adding strings together and didn't pay attention to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I might write it like this:

```js
const extract = data => Object.values (
  data .reduce ((a, {Geo, SalesStage, PipelineValue}) => {
    const key = Geo + '~' + SalesStage
    return {...a, [key]: {
      Geo,
      SalesStage,
      count: (((a[key] || {}).count) || 0) + 1,
      PipelineValue: ((a[key] || {}).PipelineValue || 0) + 
                     Number(PipelineValue.replace(/,/g, ''))
    }}
  }, {})
)

const data = {pipeline: {data: [{UserName: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", PipelineValue: "3,54,000"}, {UserName: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", PipelineValue: "3,49,000"}, {UserName: "Kaviarasan Selvaraj", Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", PipelineValue: "70,000"}, {UserName: "Vivek Sharma", Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "close won", PipelineValue: "13,45,000"}]}}


console .log (extract (data .pipeline .data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We don't wrap your numeric results back up with commas.  That wouldn't be a hard thing to add if necessary.